# Azure Continuous Deployment from Visual Studio Team Services with multiple projects

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-devops

While using Github (or anything other than Visual Studio Team Services) I can use the following page to customize deployment: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Customizing-deployments

I'd like to customize my deployment as I currently have both a web app and a web api project. I want the web app to be deployed, as default it deploys the web api project. Using project Kudu the settings (.deployment file or even better, the app settings on Azure itself) works great, but not when you deploy from Visual Studio Team Services.

I've spoken with David Ebbo from Project Kudu, and he explained that VS Team Services doesn't use Kudu at all, but probably MS Build. So my question is, how to specifically deploy the web app.

I managed to change the Build Definition and specify the web app .csproj as the Projects To Build. This works. However, I also want to deploy my web api.

Deploying the web api project with Kudu is easy as I can create a separate website, connect to the some repository (and solution) and specify the Project App setting so that it deploys the correct .csproj. How should we do this for MS Build? When I change the Build Definition, it will always deploy the project specified in there.

Comment: Are you deploying websites or cloud services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just saw another answer on Stackoverflow that looks to solve this problem: [Publish Multiple Projects to Different Locations on Azure Website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21341616/publish-multiple-projects-to-different-locations-on-azure-website)