# Azure web site as virtual application/directory of other Azure web site

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, virtual-directory

I am looking to migrate an MVC website to Azure web sites. My current set up in IIS is as follows:

Main MVC site -> www.thesite.com (physical path = wwwroot/thesite)
WordPress blog for the site -> www.thesite.com/blog (physical path = wwwroot/thesiteblog)

These are two separate projects on my end. They exist in separate directories within wwwroot. On the Main MVC site, I configured a virtual directory to point www.thesite.com/blog to wwwroot/thesiteblog.

Is it possible to replicate this behavior using Azure web sites? I see there are configuration options for virtual applications and directories, but they only seem to allow pointing to other places withing the same web site. Ideally, Id like to create 2 Azure web sites, and have the /blog subdirectory of web site #1 point to the root of web site #2. I do not wish to incorporate the code from site #2 into site #1, but I would if I find that is my only option.

I cannot be the only one out there who has had this need before, yet I am having a hard time finding any current information about how to go about doing this. Any thoughts out there?

Comment: do you want them to run in 2 separate w3wp.exe? or do you just want them to be in 2 separate projects? because the former isn't possible, but the latter is.

Comment: Currently, I'm just interested in keeping the two projects separate, and configured as 2 individual Azure web sites.

Comment: Is this still a feature. I'm having trouble finding the documentation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can keep them in 2 separate projects and use the virtual directories and applications settings in Azure to publish the 2 different projects under the same site. They will run under the same application pool because in Azure currently there is a 1:1 mapping between websites and application pools. For how to, check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21341616/publish-multiple-projects-to-different-locations-on-azure-website/21346077#21346077)

Comment: I have 2 (Parent - 2.0 and child-4.5) web applications are built upon different .Net versions. Use of 1 single app pool is the reason this setup is not working. Any suggestions how I can get 2 different .Net version based web apps to go under the same Azure webapp ?