# How to install Ghost inside an existing node.js application on Azure?

Tags: node.js, azure, express, azure-web-app-service, ghost-blog

Can you install Ghost (http://ghost.org) so that it runs inside an existing node.js express application (like this: {my domain}/blog)?

I'm using Azure Websites to host the site.

Please note: I would prefer a generic solution that can run on any platform... however I thought I would mention that it's on Azure in case it provides a simple way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do that.

You will need to:

### 1. Add a new blog application

Basically go to portal -> CONFIGURE tab -> scroll all the way to the bottom and add something like this

[image: add application]

### 2. Configure Ghost to run on a sub folder

publish Ghost to whichever folder you mapped to your application in the step above. 
You can use FTP, [webdeploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21341616/publish-multiple-projects-to-different-locations-on-azure-website/21346077#21346077) or SCM (`https://<YouSiteName>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole` 
that's what I choose and my folder layout looks like this

[image: console]

*igonre the `deployments` folder, it's not related to this*

in your `config.js` for Ghost, under the `Production` environment node make sure you have the url as

```
production: {
        url: 'http://<YourSiteName>.azurewebsites.net/blog',
        mail: {
          ......
         }
 }
```

### 3. Fix the main site's `web.config`

go to your main sites web.config and wrap the whole `<system.webServer>` element in a `<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">`

basically your `web.config` should have looked like this

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
         <handlers>
              <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
        </handlers>
        <rewrite>
             <rules>
                 <!-- Some rewrite rules -->
             </rules>
        </rewrite>
        ....
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

and now it should look like this

```
<configuration>
    <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
         <system.webServer>
              <handlers>
                   <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
             </handlers>
             <rewrite>
                  <rules>
                      <!-- Some rewrite rules -->
                  </rules>
             </rewrite>
             ....
       </system.webServer>
   </location>
</configuration>
```

*notice this is for the main site that is the Express.js in your case not the Ghost site*

that should be all you need to do.

Comment: had this issue on iis7 (my personal server) using iisnode. I used step 3 to fix my issue "
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
" and "Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'add' with unique key attribute 'name' set to 'iisnode' " at `config source: <add name="iisnode" path="index.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can install it as an addition to your existing site, but Ghost exists as a deployable template in the Azure Web Sites gallery, under **Blogs**:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response but this does not solve my problem.  This will create a separate Azure Website instance.  I need to use the same Azure Website instance.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the complete answer you were looking for, but these instructions on how to manually install Ghost on Azure Websites might help guide you in the right direction:
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToInstallTheNodejsGhostBloggingSoftwareOnAzureWebsites.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the response but this does not solve my problem.  I've read through this article before and it looks helpful if you're trying to get a stand alone instance of Ghost running on Azure.   I need to use the same Azure Website instance.