# Publish Azure Website to non-root folder from PowerShell

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment, azure-web-app-service, azure-powershell

I'm testing my assumptions at the moment. I have my Asp.Net MVC application located at `www.myapp.com/app` and a third-party CMS system on `www.myapp.com/`.

The web-site is set up like described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21346077/809357)

At the moment I can publish both of the applications separately and manually from Visual Studio and it works fine.

However, I'm trying to publish my application from a build server where I'm using Azure Power-Shell scriplets:

```
PS> Publish-AzureWebsiteProject -Name myApp -Package MyWebDeployPackage.zip
```

However, [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn722468.aspx) does not mention if you can publish with this scriplet to a non-root folder.

Any way I can publish an application to `~/app` from a command line?

**UPD**: I can publish from `msbuild` via

```
msbuild .\SolutionName.sln /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=ProfileName /p:Password=passwordForAzurePublishing /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=true
```

Where `ProfileName` is a web-deploy profile configured to deploy to sub-folder of Azure Web-Site and `Password` is deployment password from Azure profile.

However this is not an optimal solution: to deploy to test and to production environment, I need to build the application twice, which I'd like to avoid: if I compile views, it takes 7-10 minutes (we have 800 views). Doing this twice is a waste of time.

**UPD 2**: Created an issue on Azure SDK Tools repository: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-tools/issues/2667

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible from PowerShell, but I might be mistaken. Looking at their publish code here https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-tools/blob/master/src/ServiceManagement/Services/Commands.Utilities/Websites/WebsitesClient.cs#L1136-L1168

and also here https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-tools/blob/master/src/ServiceManagement/Services/Commands.Utilities/Websites/WebsitesClient.cs#L1218-L1229

they don't have a parameter for the app name, and the code in the second link builds the site name/slot manually.

I would say open an issue here https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-tools/issues for this and somebody from the Azure PowerShell team should look at it.

Comment: Yep, I did look on the same code-base and did not find any evidence of what I need to be possible. Thanks for having another look and verifying my findings.