# Publish multiple projects to different virtual directories on Azure using TFS

Tags: azure, tfs

I have 2 different solutions in 2 different TFS repositories, and I'd like to deploy them both on the same domain. The first one in the "naked" url www.myurl.com and the second one in the virtual directory www.myurl.com/myapp/

Exactly what they are trying to do here:

[Publish Multiple Projects to Different Locations on Azure Website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21341616/publish-multiple-projects-to-different-locations-on-azure-website)

Just I'd like to use TFS to do the publishing, instead of doing it from my machine. Is that possible, by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did wonder about the same question: [Publish Azure Website to non-root folder from PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24376643/publish-azure-website-to-non-root-folder-from-powershell) and there was no good answer. I raised an issue with MS Azure team: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-tools/issues/2667

One of the solutions was to manage the application through powershell: https://gist.github.com/trentmswanson/d55a6e8e78572b82c3ad

And then publish with `WebDeploy.exe` into the subdirectory. However, there is no tooling available for this task, so you'll have to come up with it yourself.