# Create blog's subdomain for ASP.NET & Wordpress

Tags: azure, subdomain, web-hosting

G'day

I have web page www.mypage.com which is written on ASP.NET, domain name bought from godaddy and hosted at Microsoft Azure.

I want to create blog hosted at Azure, using wordpress, which opens as blog.mypage.com or mypage.com/blog.

Should I configure that at azure? or mypage project? or godaddy?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup a CNAME of blog.mypage.com on godaddy (or whoever your DNS hosting is provided by) to point to the Azure (websites, I presume?) address.

Comment: hm, I own only mypage.com, to create subdomain godaddy asks to buy hosting which I don't actually need. http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/4652/managing-your-hosting-account-subdomains

Comment: You don't want a hosting plan site, just the DNS part.  I don't use godaddy, but this might help (see the Adding or Editing CNAME Records section): http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/680/managing-dns-for-your-domain-names (the alias would be "blog" and it would point to the azure website address)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can have your blog as a Virtual Application and you would not need to pay for extra site if you have blog sitting in  `www.mysite.com/blog`.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21346077/809357) on how to configure virtual application: