# Thinktecture Identity server v3 with ASP.NET Identity architecture

Tags: oauth-2.0, owin, jwt, thinktecture-ident-server, asp.net-identity

I am new to Thinktecture Identity Server, but i've read up on it's capability to serve as an OAuth provider with Aspnet.Identity as the user store.

I have a current azure website running and i want to implement an Azure Mobile Service (AMS). After many research, it led to me Thinktecture Identity Server v3 (beta3-2). I am planning to use JsonWebToken (JWT) as a way of authenticating & authorizing requests from native client.

I added this bit into my azure website application in `Startup.Auth`

```
        var factory = new Thinktecture.IdentityManager.Host.AspNetIdentityIdentityManagerFactory("MyConnectionStringHere");
        app.UseIdentityManager(new IdentityManagerConfiguration()
        {
            IdentityManagerFactory = factory.Create
        });
```

Then my Azure website stopped working and i noticed that it seems to overwrite my website and try to make it as a claim app in it's entirety. Are we supposed to use a separate instance of an application or is it possible to "co-host" an Identity Server **as well as** my azure website?

Answer (score 0):

It is common to run identity server as a separate role/site but you can also run it in its own virtual application within the same deployment. I have never used azurewebsites (I mostly use azure roles), but this looks relevant to your case:
[Publish Multiple Projects to Different Locations on Azure Website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21341616/publish-multiple-projects-to-different-locations-on-azure-website/21346077#21346077)