# Subsite | Azure website migrate | MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, azure-web-app-service

We are trying to migrate MVC4 applications to Azure website  since there is no option of creating sub site in azure website so below code from MVC 4 is breaking

Can someone tell me what needs to be done to fix the issue for below so that it can be used both in MVC 4 and azure website

**window.location.href = '/**SubSite**/Customer/Details?**

As there is no sub site inn azure above code was breaking

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What's a subsite? Do you mean Area?

Comment: Sorry, Actually we have parent website and sub site inside them like   --- Daddy.Com/BigBoss  -- Daddy.Com/MostTalented dady.com is parent website and Bigboss and Mosttalented. Now this is not supported in azure

Comment: So in each folder a separate MVC application. If Azure doesn't support that, you should consider converting it to one application using Areas.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Websites supports running sub-applications under your site like IIS does. The only difference is that you can't run them in separate Application Pools like you can do with IIS.
[Check this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21346077/3234163) for more details on how to configure that.