# deploying a mvc and wcf on Azure

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to deploy my app to azure.

The buildup is as followed:

- .Net WCF REST Service witch does data handling
- .Net MVC App witch is the site

So I deployed my service on 1 site (xxService.azurewebsites.net) and the App on the other site xxApp.azurewebsites.net

I offcorse made in the config of both apps to allow orginin and stuff:

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value=<<Address to app>> />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,DELETE,HEAD,PUT,OPTIONS" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
  <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
```

Now the Error I am getting is that the connection is not allowing `OPTION` call's to the `SERVICE`:

OPTIONS `<some POST endpoint>`
 XMLHttpRequest cannot load `<some POST endpoint>`. Invalid HTTP status code 405

I also tryed to deploy the WCF on a subfolder in the MVC app with Virtual directory but that is not working at all.

Hope anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Mybe someone will end up with the same problem.

Follow the solution in this post and you will get it working
[Publish Multiple Projects to Different Locations on Azure Website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21341616/publish-multiple-projects-to-different-locations-on-azure-website/21346077#21346077)