# Two Azure Cloud Services Single Domain

Tags: azure, multi-tenant

In IIS you can create an Application on a site so now I want to try and accomplish the same on Azure Cloud Service:

tenant.mysite.com - One Cloud Service
tenant.mysite.com/api - Another Cloud Service

The reason I want it done like this is cause this is a multi-tenant site and the api needs to be called with the tenants URL.

Is there any way out the box to do this with Azure? Am I looking at the whole solution wrong or do I have to look into doing a proxy of sorts?

Comment: Is it right that you don't want to use WebApp (aka WebSites) for this purpose but Cloud Service? In case WebApp is good for you just check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21341616/publish-multiple-projects-to-different-locations-on-azure-website

Answer (score 0):

I did host the application similar to what you have did. 
There are a few points that you will need to take care of 
1. Overlapping sections of web.config file should be locked using `<location path='.'.... >` tags
2. Proper references for the dlls to be given

This is easily achieved in both the Azure websites and Azure Cloud Services. The link that explains how you can get started is given below. Post questions if  you have tried this and run into some issues.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2014/09/22/deploying-multiple-virtual-directories-to-a-single-azure-website.aspx