# Azure: Will I be able to use source control integration?

Tags: visual-studio, azure

Currently, my visual studio solution has 3 projects:

- MVC project - to be deployed at say www.something.com
- Web Api - to be deployed at api.something.com
- SPA application - to be deployed at app.something.com

Will I be able to host all of these just through VSO source control? I am not sure if azure would be able to host the applications at respective sub-domains without explicitly defining them?

Can anybody please clarify? And what would be the best approach?

Comment: Please edit your question to be more specific. Azure's App Service (including web sites) has source control integration built-in. You didn't clarify what you're using.

Comment: Actually I want an answer for both Cloud service and Web app service.

Answer (score 1):

if you host your application on Azure App service, there is continues deployment service. You can have your code next to your site (Local Git https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-publish-source-control/) or you can have your code in supported repository e.g github/bitbucket etc ..

And Azure App Service supports virtual directly, you can have multiple apps in the same site. see detail answer from here [Publish Multiple Projects to Different Locations on Azure Website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21341616/publish-multiple-projects-to-different-locations-on-azure-website/21346077#21346077)