# How to configure multi level virtual directory in azure portal?

Tags: azure, web-config, azure-web-app-service, virtual-directory, azureportal

The azure portal allows me to add single level virtual directory in its configuration settings.

[image]

but I don't know how to add multi level virtual directory in azure?

[image]

It throws the below error while saving the settings.

```
Failed to update web app settings: ["{\"Code\":\"BadRequest\",\"Message\":\"Invalid virtual path '/showcase/test/app' has no parent.\",\"Target\":null,\"Details\":
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the [Virtual Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationHost/sites/site/application/virtualDirectory). It seems that the parent path must already exist if you want to add the multi-level sub virtual directory. You can see this.

[image]

You can get more references from other SO answers.

[Publish Multiple Projects to Different Locations on Azure Website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21341616/publish-multiple-projects-to-different-locations-on-azure-website/21346077#21346077)

Answer (score 0):

It's a virtual path so you shouldn't need to drill down, below is what you should be doing.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wf1sa.png)

[image: Image 1]

Hope this helps

Comment: I can get single level virtual path (https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/showcaseapp) as I mentioned earlier. My requirement is to get multilevel virtual path like this
https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/showcase/test/app.

Is your suggetion meet my requirement?