# AzureDevOps 2019 - Linking Test Runs to User Stories

Tags: azure-devops

Is it possible to link the Azure Test Plans Test Runs results to a Test Case/User Story? I can link the Test Case to a User Story and get the report on that but I'm looking at getting the Test Run metrics etc. linked to a Test Case or a User Story so that that I can report on that?

Pleas advise

Thanks

Greg

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Publish Multiple Projects to Different Locations on Azure Website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21341616/publish-multiple-projects-to-different-locations-on-azure-website)

Answer (score 0):

> I'm looking at getting the Test Run metrics etc. linked to a Test Case or a User Story so that that I can report on that?

Sorry for any inconvenience.

There is a great extension to add the test run results in the test case:

[View Latest Test Result](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=keesverhaar.viewlatesttestresult)

Besides, there is a ticket about [link Test Results back to ANY work item type, especially User Stories](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/451436/need-ability-to-link-test-results-back-to-any-work.html) on the Developer Community, you could check this thread for some details.

Hope this helps.