# Auto deploy specific project in solution to Azure

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-web-app-service, azure-devops

I'm using Visual Studio Online for my TFS needs, and I have a pretty big solution which contains several web projects.

How can I set up automatic deployment of a specific project in the solution to a specific website on Azure?

Comment: Are you referring to Azure Website or Azure Webrole?

Comment: @AmitApple An Azure Website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default workflow used to deploy in VSO does not seem to handle this scenario.
The "first" web project found within the solution is chosen for deployment according to [this discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/95f161f6-9370-43ad-9ac5-714f8978cc5e/continuous-integration-deploying-wrong-project-from-solution?forum=azuregit). Note that the discussion relates to git on VSO but it seems to hold true for builds using the VSO CI workflow.

According to the discussion changing the project names to influence the ordering should/might work but results seem mixed.

We chose to add a second solution only containing the web-project to deploy, its dependencies and tests. This will not work if there are dependencies on other web-projects.

Also take not of [this article on a configuration-based approach](http://peter.orneholm.com/post/84647111808/deploy-to-multiple-azure-websites-with-visual-studio), [a question that this one might be a duplicate of](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21311390/468244) or [a question concerning actual deployment of multiple projects into one site](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21341616/468244).