# Azure: How to fix 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' in Deplyoment Center

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-web-app-service

Im struggling with azure app service. Everything seems to work perfectly but I can't build my project through **Deployment Center**. It looks like a solution with many projects is not recognised.

I've tried even to add into app settings variable [**"PROJECT"**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34853640/7884071) and within [**.deployment**](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Customizing-deployments#deploying-a-specific-aspnet-or-aspnet-core-project-file) file. But it didn't help.

I've prepared  two recipes to reproduce it.

This won't work

```sh
mkdir AzureProject && cd AzureProject &&
dotnet new sln --name AzureProject &&
dotnet new webapi --name WebApi &&
dotnet sln AzureProject.sln add WebApi/WebApi.csproj &&
git init &&
git add . &&
git commit -v &&
git remote add azure {azure_git_repo} &&
git push azure master
```

And this will

```sh
dotnet new webapi --name WebApi && 
cd WebApi git init && 
git add . && 
git commit -v && 
git remote add azure {azure_git_repo} && 
git push azure master
```

Here is the failing result:

```
TIME    ACTIVITY    LOG
11:08:26 AM Updating branch 'master'.   
11:08:27 AM Updating submodules.    
11:08:28 AM Preparing deployment for commit id '82434122e8'.    
Show Logs...
11:08:28 AM App container will begin restart within 10 seconds. 
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

**It works locally after running dotnet build.**

Edit: I've tried to generate solution + project through Visual Studio 2019 and only add remote + push but same result.